# elm: decode json that contains a json array

Tags: elm, json-deserialization

So I need to decode a `json` that contains a `json array` in `elm`. Here is my model:

```
type alias ValidationResult =
    { parameter : String
    , errorMessage : String
    }


type alias ErrorResponse =
    { validationErrors : List ValidationResult }
```

And here is an example of the `json`:

```
{"ValidationErrors": [{"Parameter": "param1","ErrorMessage": "message 1"},{"Parameter": "param2","ErrorMessage": "error message 2"}]}
```

I've tried to create a `ValidationResult` decoder, like:

```
decodeValidationResults : Decoder ValidationResult
decodeValidationResults =
  map2 ValidationResult
    (at [ "Parameter" ] Json.Decode.string)
    (at [ "ErrorMessage" ] Json.Decode.string)
```

But I don't know how to proceed further.

I am using `elm` 0.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! You just need a decoder that decodes the `ErrorResponse` type. To do so, create another decoder that uses a list of the decoder you've already created, assuming the field name is `"ValidationErrors"`:

```elm
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

decodeErrorResponse : Decoder ErrorResponse
decodeErrorResponse =
    map ErrorResponse
        (field "ValidationErrors" (list decodeValidationResults))
```

One bit of advice: You can use `Json.Decode.field` instead of `Json.Decode.at` when there is only a single level. You can rewrite `decodeValidationResults` as this:

```elm
decodeValidationResults : Decoder ValidationResult
decodeValidationResults =
  map2 ValidationResult
    (field "Parameter" string)
    (field "ErrorMessage" string)
```

Comment: I knew that it has to be something like that but I didn't knew about (list decodeValidationResults). Thanks