# elm: get first error message from a list

Tags: list, elm

Giving the model (related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124963/elm-decode-json-that-contains-a-json-array/41125085)):

```
type alias ValidationResult =
    { parameter : String
    , errorMessage : String
    }


type alias ErrorResponse =
    { validationErrors : List ValidationResult }


decodeValidationResults : Decoder ValidationResult
decodeValidationResults =
  map2 ValidationResult
    (field "Parameter" string)
    (field "ErrorMessage" string)

decodeErrorResponse : Decoder ErrorResponse
decodeErrorResponse =
    map ErrorResponse
        (field "ValidationErrors" (list decodeValidationResults))
```

I want to create a function that returns the forst error message from the ErrorResponse. Here is what I've tried:

```
firstErrorMessage : Decoder CardEngineErrorResponse -> String
firstErrorMessage decoder response =
    case List.head response.validationErrors of
        Just something ->
            something.errorMessage

        Nothing ->
            toString ""
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
The definition of `firstErrorMessage` does not match its type annotation.

The type annotation for `firstErrorMessage` says it always returns:
 
     String
 
 But the returned value (shown above) is a:
 
     { b | validationErrors : List { a | errorMessage : String } } -> String
 
 Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.
```

Any of you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to get the first error message from an `ErrorResponse` value, you don't need to reference `Decoder`:

```elm
firstErrorMessage : ErrorResponse -> String
firstErrorMessage response =
    case List.head response.validationErrors of
        Just something ->
            something.errorMessage

        Nothing ->
            ""
```

or, more succinctly:

```elm
firstErrorMessage : ErrorResponse -> String
firstErrorMessage response =
    List.head response.validationErrors
        |> Maybe.map .errorMessage
        |> Maybe.withDefault ""
```

If you are instead trying to do this all within context of a decoder, you can do so using `Json.Decode.map`:

```elm
firstErrorMessageDecoder : Decoder String
firstErrorMessageDecoder =
    decodeErrorResponse
        |> map firstErrorMessage
```

One more note: When something has the possibility of failing, it is often best to retain the notion of `Maybe`. Instead of defaulting to the empty string which callers will have to know about, you can build a stronger API by returning a `Maybe String`:

```elm
firstErrorMessage : ErrorResponse -> Maybe String
firstErrorMessage response =
    List.head response.validationErrors
        |> Maybe.map .errorMessage
```

Comment: If you will ever come to Madrid, please tell me, because I own you crates of beer ;)